# Error recover database RMAN-06054

Tags: oracle, recovery, rman

I deleted the test database, and now I want to restore it back, when I try to recover the database I get this error.
Everything I had at the database is there and everything works fine.

How can I fix this error?

```
unable to find archived log
archived log thread=1 sequence=2
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 01/28/2019 11:49:40
RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown archived log for thread 1 with sequence 2 and starting SCN of 422743

SQL> select sequence# from v$archived_log;

 SEQUENCE#
----------
    11
    12
     1
    11
     1
    12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal when performing an incomplete recovery without specifying where recovery should stop.

If sequence 1 is the last log sequence that was backed up, you can avoid the above error by using instead of:

```
recover database;
```

this:

```
recover database until sequence 2;
```

Comment: Same error with different sequence `RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown archived log for thread 1 with sequence 1 and starting SCN of 628258`

Comment: @petar No, that is not the same error. That is a different log sequence, with a different SCN.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus '/ as sysdba'

sql>alter database open resetlogs;
```

Once you execute the above command, you should get the `Database altered` message which indicates that the database opened successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).